# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Range

Tags: java, urlencode, apache-commons

I am trying to encode html view source as `\u03C4`. Got help from this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280607/stringescapeutils-not-handling-utf-8) but first I used `org.apache.commons.lang3` but seen [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817480/why-was-org-apache-common-lang3-stringescapeutils-deprecated) that its moved to `org.apache.commons.text`

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.UnicodeUnescaper;

public class HTMLEncoder extends Common {

    public static String encode(String source) {
        String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(source);
        String utfChars = new UnicodeUnescaper().translate(escaped);
    return utfChars; 
    }
}
```

This code throws the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Range
org.apache.commons.text.translate.NumericEntityEscaper.<init>(NumericEntityEscaper.java:46)
org.apache.commons.text.translate.NumericEntityEscaper.between(NumericEntityEscaper.java:85)
org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.<clinit>(StringEscapeUtils.java:162)
parvaz.aero.commons.method.HTMLEncoder.encode(HTMLEncoder.java:8)
parvaz.aero.user.categories.controller.SelectAll.doGet(SelectAll.java:60)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**Question-1:** Its using apache common text package but throwing error about apache commons lang3?
**Question-2:** How to fix it?

Any advice please

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.java) it looks like there is a dependency on the Apache Commons Lang 3 library.  You can download it from [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi).

I was able to resolve the error by importing the *commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar* file into my project, the same way I imported the *commons-text-1.9.jar* file (your file versions may be different).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be issue with dependency versions,when we use commons-text and commons-lang3 together.For me it worked well after using 1.11.0 for commons-text and 3.13.0 for commons-lang3

"org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.11.0"
"org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0"